# Dynamic context menu on PrimeNG p-tree component

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG UI library v10 in an Angular application. I have a `p-tree` component that show a list of items that must show a context menu when the user right-clicks on them. The problem is that each item will have different options, depending on its type. So, I'd need to run some logic to show/hide the appropriate context menu options before they're popped. This is the code:

```html
<p-tree [value]="treeItems" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedItem" [contextMenu]="treeContextMenu"></p-tree>

<p-contextMenu #treeContextMenu [model]="menuItems"></p-contextMenu>
```

I've tried binding the `contextMenu` property to a method that returns the `ContextMenu` reference and run the logic there, but it didn't work. Something like:

```js
<p-tree [value]="treeItems" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedItem" [contextMenu]="buildContextMenu()"></p-tree>

<p-contextMenu #treeContextMenu [model]="menuItems"></p-contextMenu>

// IN THE COMPONENT CODE:

@ViewChild('treeContextMenu') treeContextMenu: ContextMenu;

public buildContextMenu(): ContextMenu {
  // Get the tree selected item to see which menu options should be visible
  const menuItemsToShow = this.getItemMenuOptions();

  // Update the context menu items (so it'll be updated in the 'treeContextMenu' component)
  this.menuItems = menuItemsToShow;

  // Return the reference to the context menu
  return this.treeContextMenu;
}
```

The above code shows the context menu, but I can't click on any option (it does nothing). Another approach would be to add a `contextmenu` event listener to each of the tree items to show a custom context menu for each of them, but I don't like it, as there could be potentially hundreds of items, with its corresponding listeners. Any suggestion on a more optimal approach?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and solved it using ngDoCheck hook to watch selected node in p-tree. When any changes detected on selected node -even if left or right click- menuContent items rearranged. So, each time user can get right menu content items.

```js
<p-tree [value]="treeData" [filter]="true" 
    [contextMenu]="contextMenu" selectionMode="single" 
    [(selection)]="selectedDocumentFolder">
    
export class DocumentFoldersComponent implements OnInit {
  // Set initial value important to catch first change
  selectedDocumentFolder: any = null;
  contextMenuItems: MenuItem[];

  constructor(injector: Injector, private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    super(injector);
    this.differ = this.differs.find({}).create();
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    const change = this.differ.diff(this);
    if (change) {
      change.forEachChangedItem((item) => {
        console.log("item changed", item);
        if (item.key === "selectedDocumentFolder") {
          this.initContextMenu();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  initContextMenu() {
    // do your context menu logic here according to new selected node
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a really interesting approach! I'll give it a try when I have the chance. Thanks!